# Pass a targeted method as a parameter

Tags: c#

first of all, my english is not very good so if you could be kind it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Now my problem, like I said in the title, I would like to pass a "method name" as a parameter in another method. Like a picture is worth thousand words, there is a chunk of my function:

```
    public void RemoveDecimalPoints(TextBox txtBoxName, Func<string, TextBox> txtBoxMethod)
    {
        //Some Code

        txtBoxName.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtBoxMethod);
    }
```

I want the second parameter to point to this other method:

```
    private void txtIncomeSelfValue1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
```

Sorry if im not clear for some, I lack some vocabulary...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are calling this `RemoveDecimalPoints` method from the same class that contains the `txtIncomeSelfValue1_KeyPress` method you could pass it like this:

```
RemoveDecimalPoints(someTextBox, this.txtIncomeSelfValue1_KeyPress);
```

but you will have to modify the signature as `Func<string, TextBox>` doesn't match the `txtIncomeSelfValue1_KeyPress` method:

```
public void RemoveDecimalPoints(TextBox txtBoxName, KeyPressEventHandler txtBoxMethod)
{
    //Some Code
    txtBoxName.KeyPress += txtBoxMethod;
}
```

Comment: had to give you an upvote - your answer was (independently) almost exactly the same as mine. :-)

Comment: Tanks for your help! I tried that but not the good way, in txtBoxName.KeyPress += txtBoxMethod; I was using txtIncomeSelfValue1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtBoxMethod); I was close! lol ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to write your code like this:

```
RemoveDecimalPoints(txtBoxName, txtIncomeSelfValue1_KeyPress);
```

then you can use:

```
public void RemoveDecimalPoints(
    TextBox txtBoxName,
    KeyPressEventHandler txtBoxMethod)
{
    //Some Code

    txtBoxName.KeyPress += txtBoxMethod;
}
```

If you want to use a `string` then you need to use reflection and your signature would need to look like this:

```
void RemoveDecimalPoints(TextBox txtBoxName, string txtBoxMethod)
```